# DynamoDB table format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like some insight into how to best design my DynamoDB tables for the following use case and why. I have read [the best practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html), but I am not sure I fully understand enough yet.

The primary use is a weekly entry for each group of users. I need to list these entries sorted by most recent entries for each user group. I also need to be able to easily(or quickly) get the most recent entry for each group.

My first naive idea before reading the article was to use separate tables for each group and then each entry just had a unique partition key and a sort key on a date converted to seconds from the epoch. But after reading that article this approach seems to violate the design of partitions because won't it make each item a new partition?

I realize the most recent entry could be cached quite easily in my web servers but am curious to see if that effects the design in anyway.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the preferred table design should look like this:

- **user groups** as partition key
- **timestamp** as sort key

This is not violation any partition design, because in a table with primary keys based on partition and sort keys you are allowed to use the same partition key on several items as long as they have different sort keys. This way you can easily query for timestamp-sorted user group entries and also easily e.g. get the latest entry.

If you want to make full use of your provisioned throughput you have to take care that you data is **spread somehow evenly across the partition key values**. If you have 20 partitions and only one or two of them are heavily accessed you will notice a heavy performance decrease.

In your scenario however, where an entry is added each week to each partition, the above design will work very well.

Comment: Awesome. After sleeping on it last night this same idea came to my head. Thanks for the advice on throughput. I had not considered that much.

Comment: this doesn't cover efficiently (i.e. no scan or multi queries) "I also need to be able to easily(or quickly) get the most recent entry for each group."

Comment: Yes it does. A query with `ScanIndexForward=false` (descending) and `Limit=1` will return the newest entry of a user group. I don't think there is a more performant way.